# Generating Closed form for generating functuions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am trying to find the closed form for the generating function of $x+x^2+x^3+...$

My inital answer is $\frac{x}{1-x}$, but I am having trouble seeing how i got to the answer.

Comment: $(1-x) \times (1 + x + \cdots + x^n) = 1 - x^{n+1}.$  For $~\displaystyle |x| < 1, ~\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{n+1} = 0.$

Comment: *geometric series*

Answer (score 1):

If you set $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^n$ for $x\in(-1,1)$

Then you can notice $xf(x)=f(x)-x\iff (x-1)f(x)=-x\iff f(x)=\frac x{1-x}$ (denominator not zero, since we placed ourselves on $|x|<1$)

You can also get it from the partial sum of a geometric series:

$S_n(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\to \dfrac 1{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ and $n\to\infty$ since $x^n\to 0$

$f(x)=S_\infty(x)-1=\frac 1{1-x}-1=\frac x{1-x}$